# C# XML Father-Son update can not save

Tags: c#, xml, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm trying to update an existing app.
I was asked previously to simply clean out an xml file for escape characters, which were coming to us, prior to them being pulled through to the company system. Doing this allowed us the option of avoiding writing inside an app written 7 years ago and working fine (but ZERO documentation)

It actually worked fine with

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetFiles(test, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("&amp;"))
        {
            i++;
        }
        //Replace incorrect characters
        else if (lines[i].Contains("&"))
        {
            log.Info(saveName);
            log.Error("Incorrect '&' Detected: Changing to '&amp;'");
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("&", "&amp;");
            log.Info(lines[i]);
        }

    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(d, lines);
}
```

And maybe too easily as I have been asked to try to integrate this with the main app, to prevent the operators having to do the pre-clean.

I know (well I believe) that I am missing the corresponding `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(d, lines);` in the following code but I can not get it or anything else to work.
The "replace" is working as the WriteLine is showing the corrected line(s) but I can not get the system to hold the changes.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

ms.Position = 0;
List<string> rows = new List<string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    string line;
    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("&"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            line = line.Replace("&", "&amp;");
            sw.Write(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never save the `MemoryStream` to a file.  Also, what happens if `line` has more than one `&`?

Comment: It's one of those that we know. It's a set list group which is imported but a vendor of a vendor of a client has made a unilateral change and management here don't feel that it is worth the 6 months of hassle to get them to remove the escape characters

Comment: The stream is converted to string later on (which is saved) but it is not holding the change of & to &amp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson is "when amending a large app, make sure to read it all".

For some reason the original developer decided to dip back in to the zip file (where these files were received) and extract the whole thing again for the Stream.

Changed that and it all works and is running much faster as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how important for you is to write a log, but seems you can do the same using something like this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("test.xml");
text = Regex.Replace(text, "&(?!amp;)", "&amp;"); 
File.WriteAllText("test.xml", text);
```

It should also cover the case when there are more then one & symbol in one string (the original code will not handle it - so if the sting is something like '&hello&', it will be processed as '&hello&').

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tomorrow. I can capture that log data in several other points TBH.